# Dynamic if-then Code

Tags: java, decision-tree

I'm using Decision Tree algorithm and I get if-then rules (returned as text) for example:

```
if(Parameter1 > 10) then
   if(Parameter2< 5) then do A
   else do B
else do C
```

I want to use these rules in order to get decisions for few items: item(Parameter1, Parameter2) example: item1(15, 5), item2(10, 20), ...
Problem is, the if-then rules are dynamic and I want to write a code capable of reading this rules and apply them on items.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  It sounds like you need to build a decision tree as a data structure and apply it to classify some inputs.

Comment: To make them "dynamic", use variables instead of literals: `int limit = 10; if (parameter1 > limit) ...`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Problem is, how to write this in a Java code ? I haven't tried any thing I don't know how to solve this. Some ideas ?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I don't know how much if-then rules there are before applying decision tree. Each time I use it (on new data) I get a new set of rules

Comment: @Zahzah are the rules always nested? or they may be tree-ordered?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou They can be tree-ordered, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flip this around and use Predicates to implement your tests.  For example,

```
public class GreaterThan implements Predicate<Integer> {
    private final int point;

    public GreaterThan(final int point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public boolean test(final Integer incoming) {
        return incoming > point;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class LessThan implements Predicate<Integer> {
  private final int point;

  public LessThan(final int point) {
      this.point = point;
  }

  public boolean test(final Integer incoming) {
    return incoming < point;
  }
}
```

And so on.  You can then use this to dynamically construct logical checks because your tests are now functional.

```
Predicate<Integer> gt10 = new GreaterThan(10);
Predicate<Integer> lt5 = new LessThan(5);

if(gt10.test(Parameter1)) then
    if(lt5.test(Parameter2)) then do A
    else do B
else do C
```

Wrap the execution of A, B and C in functions and you're on your way to a flexible system.   Now you're dealing with functional objects, you can structure things dynamically - instead of the fixed test shown above, you can compose tests and consequences as required.

Comment: See the the two if-else-then I used in this example, it's not always like this i could've got 3 or 4 instead.

Comment: That's what I mean by "Now you're dealing with functional objects, you can structure things dynamically - instead of the fixed test shown above, you can compose tests and consequences as required."

Comment: @Zahzah then you need to create a tree of such predicates